# array_map not allow to pass object in use()

Tags: php, array-map

I am trying this:

```
array_map(function($data) use ($this->id) {
   //code
}, $arr);
```

I'm getting an error that I can not pass an object to `use()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: how about reasigning as `$id = $this->id`, then using it in `use ($id)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything from `$this` to the closure. `$this` is available in closures by default. Example:

```php
class A {
    private $id = 500;

    function B() {
        $arr = [1, 2, 3];
        array_map(
            function($data) {
                echo "I'm data $data with id {$this->id}\n";
            },
            $arr
        );
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->B();
```

This code will print

```
I'm data 1 with id 500
I'm data 2 with id 500
I'm data 3 with id 500
```

Or if you want to pass anything to the `use` construct instead of using `$this` directly, just assign your value to a variable and then pass this simple variable to `use`. You can not list expressions in `use`.